# I am learning twitter-bootstrap and some of the code is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I have a div and I gave the div a class of hello col-sm-4. I went to my CSS code and gave hello a color of gray. But it is not making the four small columns gray

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>bootstrap</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootsrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com                                    /bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="dark col-sm-4">test</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Post the contents of `styles/bootsrap.css`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.dark
{
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>bootstrap</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootsrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com                                    /bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="dark col-sm-4">test</div>
      <div class="dark col-sm-4">test</div>
      <div class="dark col-sm-4">test</div>
      <div class="dark col-sm-4">test</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

You need to add four times ...so it will come out 4.

`col-sm-4, col-sm-4, col-sm-4, col-sm-4  == TOTAL 12`